# Problems using the inflect module for multiple members

Tags: python

If there is more than 1 member, I would like the result to be:

```
These may be members
```

If there is 1 member, I would like the result to be:

```
This may be a member
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import inflect

member_count = 2
p.num(member_count)
print(p.plural_adj('This', member_count),'may be',p.an(p.plural('member', member_count),member_count))
```

One member works correctly:

```
This may be a member
```

But 2 members does not work correctly:

```
These may be 2 members
```

I am not sure how to get rid of the '2'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to make `p.an()` conditional based on `member_count` but it isn't clean and shows a limitation of `inflect`:

```
>>> member_count = 2
>>> print(p.plural_adj('This', member_count),
...                    'may be',
...                    p.an('member') if member_count == 1 else p.plural('member'))
These may be members
>>> member_count = 1
>>> print(p.plural_adj('This', member_count),
...                    'may be',
...                    p.an('member') if member_count == 1 else p.plural('member'))
This may be a member
```

Comment: Not pretty, but works like a charm. Thanks. btw I think you mean 'limitation of inflect', not 'limitation of inspect'